# How to extrapolate outside the range of a 2d-bivariate spline with `interpolate.Rbf` (similar to `fill_value='extrapolate'` in interp1d)

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am trying to extrapolate past the given range of a 2d spline using `interpolate.Rbf`.

Insert the str from here: https://justpaste.it/d7u7z into `data_str` (no need for `''` string hyphens)

How can I find values of `zi` outside of the bounds of `Ti`. I want to be able to find `zi` when `Ti = 0`. I.e. calculate `rbf(0,4500)`.

My code is:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, Rbf
from numpy import ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data_str = # insert the string from the url here

vol = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_str))

vol.set_index('dte',inplace=True)

valid_vol=ma.masked_invalid(vol).T

Ti=np.linspace(float((vol.index).min()),float((vol.index).max()),len(vol.index))
Ki=np.linspace(float((vol.columns).min()),float((vol.columns).max()),len(vol.columns))

Ti,Ki = np.meshgrid(Ti,Ki)

valid_Ti = Ti[~valid_vol.mask]
valid_Ki = Ki[~valid_vol.mask]
valid_vol = valid_vol[~valid_vol.mask]

zi = griddata((valid_Ti, valid_Ki), valid_vol, (Ti, Ki), method='cubic')

points = np.column_stack((Ti.ravel(), Ki.ravel()))

values = zi.ravel()
mask = ~np.isnan(values)
values = values[mask]

points = points[mask]

rbf = Rbf(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], values, function='linear')

interp_value = rbf(0.015, 4545)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = np.linspace(Ti.min(),Ti.max(),100)

y = np.linspace(Ki.min(),Ki.max(),100)
x,y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
z = rbf(x,y)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

I didn't use bisplrep with bisplev because it wasn't able to produce a spline (I read the documentation, no `s` gave a spline).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `griddata` not RBF. If you look for radial basis functions, use RBFInterpolator instead.